# CakePHP: Create array of checkboxes and update field based on whether it's set

Tags: php, cakephp, checkbox

I'm not sure if what I'm asking for is possible, but here's the scenario:

I have a foreach() loop that returns some values in HTML format:

```
<?php foreach($stuff as $s) { ?>
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo $s['Model']['data']; ?> </td>
 </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

What I need to do is put a checkbox next to each `$s['Model']['data']`, preferably with `$s['Model']['data']` as the label, and be able to set a value in a table based on whether the box is checked. So, my `edit.ctp` would look like this:

```
<?php foreach($stuff as $s) { ?>
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('flag', array('type'=>'checkbox, 'default'=>'', label=>' $s['Model']['data']', 'value'=>1 )); ?> </td>
 </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

I have no trouble displaying the above. My problem is that I don't know how to tell my controller to update the necessary field if the labeled box is checked. Here's my first run at it:

```
if($this->request->save($this->request->data)) {
    foreach($stuff as $s) {
        $this->Model->id = $s['Model']['id'];
        if(isset($this->request->data['FormName']['flag'])) {
            $this->Model->set('flag', 1);
            $this->Model->save('flag', true);
        }
    }
}
```

No errors at runtime, but nothing happens. The `flag` field in the Model I need to update remains = 0. I can debug `$stuff` and see data, so I know it's there. I also know that my edit function is hitting the foreach() loop. What might I be missing? Do I need to assign the checkbox a different value or check for whether it's set some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to identify each checkbox to the current item by modifying the name of each checkbox, otherwise it will just use the value of the last checkbox for all the items.

```
<?php foreach($stuff as $i => $s) { ?>
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('flag'.$i, array('type'=>'checkbox, 'default'=>'', label=>' $s['Model']['data']', 'value'=>1 )); ?> </td>
 </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Then in the controller look for that specific flag

```
if($this->request->save($this->request->data)) {
    foreach($stuff as $i => $s) {
        $this->Model->id = $s['Model']['id'];
        if(isset($this->request->data['FormName']['flag'.$i])) {
            $this->Model->set('flag', 1);
            $this->Model->save('flag', true);
        }
    }
}
```

Which assumes that ht elements in $stuff are always in the same order.

Comment: When I put in your modifications, I can output the indexes and confirm that each checkbox has a unique one. I'm less clear on how to modify my controller to identify which indexes are checked.

Comment: updated, essentially you have to do the same thing to access the new flag names

Comment: Success! Thanks. I was putting the index in the wrong place in my controller.